# Determine if a basis is a positively oriented basis (without using matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Given an orthonormal positively oriented basis $B=(\mathbf{i}, \mathbf{j}, \mathbf{k})$ and a real number $h$, let
$$
\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{i}-h\mathbf{k}
$$
$$
\mathbf{w} = 2\mathbf{i}-\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k}
$$
$$
\mathbf{z}= h\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}-\mathbf{k}
$$
Determine for which values of $h$ we have that $(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w},\mathbf{z})$ is a basis and it is a positively oriented basis.

I found that for $h\neq0$ and $h\neq-2$, $(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w},\mathbf{z})$ is a basis, but I cannot find the values for which $(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w},\mathbf{z})$ is a positively oriented basis.

(This exercise must be solved without using matrices!)

Comment: How do you define "positively oriented" without using the determinant?

Answer (score 3):

If you are allowed to use the determinant (it is not a matrix !) with respect to $(i,j,k)$:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&-h\\2&-1&1\\h&1&-1\end{vmatrix} \ = \ -2h-h^2$$

Using the classical result about the sign of a quadratic expression, $(v,w,z)$

- is not a basis for $h=-2$ or $h=0$.
- has the same orentation as $(i,j,k)$, i.e., is positively oriented basis iff $-2<h<0$.
- is a negatively oriented basis in the other cases: $h<-2$ or $h>0$.

Comment: I cannot use the determinant! This is an argument which the professor taught before the concepts of vector spaces, matrices, determinants, etc. I tried to use the triple product of v, w and z and verify if the module of the resulting vector is positive. Is it right?

Comment: Triple product is a determinant !

Comment: Oh right! I'm an idiot :D